# Parse hex numbers along with decimal numbers from XML with boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

I am parsing an XML file with `boost::property_tree`. The data I need to parse includes regular decimal numbers such as `42` and hex numbers such as `0xF1`. For example:

```xml
<hex>0xF1</hex>
<dec>42</dec>
```

It's easy to parse decimal numbers and convert them to `int` with `ptree::get<int>()`. However, the same call on the hex number fails.

I can work around this by parsing the hex number as a `std::string` and then using `std::istringstream` and `std::hex` to convert it to `int`. Demonstrating with code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

using std::string;
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main() {
    pt::ptree tree;

    try {
        pt::read_xml("debug.xml", tree, pt::xml_parser::no_comments);
    } catch (const pt::xml_parser_error&) {}

    int hexnum;

    // Doesn't work (throws exception)
    try {
        hexnum = tree.get<int>("hex");
    } catch (const pt::ptree_bad_data&) {
        std::cout << "caught bad ptree data exception";
    }

    // Workaround: parse as a string, then convert the string
    string hexstring;

    try {
         hexstring = tree.get<string>("hex");
         std::istringstream iss(hexstring);
         iss >> std::hex >> hexnum;
         if (!iss) throw std::ios_base::failure("invalid hex string");
    } catch (const pt::ptree_error&) {
        // get() failed
    } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& fail) {
        std::cout << fail.what();
    }

    // Parsing a regular decimal number is straightforward
    int decnum;

    try {
        decnum = tree.get<int>("dec");
    } catch (const pt::ptree_error&) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, similar to how I can convert a `std::string` into a number using `std::istringstream` with `std::hex`, `std::oct`, or `std::dec`? The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) shows that there is a `stream_translator.hpp` header file which looks promising as a way to do this -- but there's not much documentation for this file either on the Boost website or in the header file itself. The workaround with `std::istringstream` is acceptable, but `stream_translator.hpp` makes me wonder if `boost::property_tree` provides a way to do this.

I need to be able to easily switch between parsing hex and decimal numbers, just as it's easy to do so with `iss >> std::hex` or `iss >> std::dec` on `std::istringstream iss`.

(In case it matters, my compiler is VS2005. Yes, '05 not '15.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of stream_translator looks pretty simple: it has only two methods. I guess you can write your own translator and setup a hex flag. Something like this:

```
/// Implementation of Translator that uses the stream overloads.
template <typename Ch, typename Traits, typename Alloc, typename E>
class stream_translator
{
    typedef customize_stream<Ch, Traits, E> customized;
public:
    typedef std::basic_string<Ch, Traits, Alloc> internal_type;
    typedef E external_type;

    explicit stream_translator(std::locale loc = std::locale())
        : m_loc(loc)
    {}

    boost::optional<E> get_value(const internal_type &v) {
        std::basic_istringstream<Ch, Traits, Alloc> iss(v);
        iss.imbue(m_loc);
        iss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
        E e;
        customized::extract(iss, e);
        if(iss.fail() || iss.bad() || iss.get() != Traits::eof()) {
            return boost::optional<E>();
        }
        return e;
    }
    boost::optional<internal_type> put_value(const E &v) {
        std::basic_ostringstream<Ch, Traits, Alloc> oss;
        oss.imbue(m_loc);
        oss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield);
        customized::insert(oss, v);
        if(oss) {
            return oss.str();
        }
        return boost::optional<internal_type>();
    }

private:
    std::locale m_loc;
};
```

ptree itself has `get` method that accepts a translator. So you can pass your own translator there.

```
    template<class Type, class Translator>
    Type get(const path_type &path,
             const Type &default_value,
             Translator tr) const;
```

Comment: This works (+1) but isn't any easier than the workaround. I was hoping there'd be a way to do it without defining an entire translator.

Comment: I don't know I just looked at the code of boost::property_tree and I found this solution the most obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the new [`stoi`/`stol`/`stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)
with its "base" set to `0`, which will do the auto detection of the numeric base.